# How to send JSON object in body in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project, I need to make `POST` action to send object to an endpoint. I am using RestClient version 110.2.0.

But I get this error:

> Request Body should be a valid JSON object.

This is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://customdomain/registrants");
var request = new RestRequest("https://customdomain/registrants", Method.Post); 

request.AddHeader("authorization", @"Bearer " + token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

object obj = new
{
    first_name = "qqq",
    last_name = "yyy",
    email = "qqq@gmail.com"
};

var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

RestResponse result = client.Execute(request.AddJsonBody(jsonString));
```

When I try with Postman, it gets sent successfully, so the problem is in the JSON body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation on [`AddJsonBody` method](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody), you should provide the object instead of a serialized JSON string.

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://customdomain/"); 
var request = new RestRequest("registrants", Method.Post);
```

**Approach 1:**

```cs
request = request.AddJsonBody(obj);

RestResponse result = client.Execute(request);
```

**Approach 2:**

```cs
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
request = request.AddJsonBody(jsonString, forceSerialize: true);

RestResponse result = client.Execute(request);
```

**Approach 3:**

Otherwise, you should use [`AddStringBody` method](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addstringbody).

```cs
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
request = request.AddStringBody(jsonString, ContentType.Json);

RestResponse result = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Not working, I get the same error

Comment: I noticed that your resource path was wrong, remove the domain url from RestRequest, and remove the resource path from `RestClient`: `var client = new RestClient("https://customdomain/");
var request = new RestRequest("registrants", Method.Post); `

Comment: No man it is:  var request = new RestRequest("https://customdomain/registrants", Method.Post);

Comment: If you read [here](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#create-a-request), the first argument of `RestRequest` should be sub-path of base (domain) path.

Comment: So you try both `AddJsonBody` and `AddStringBody` methods, but getting the same error?

Comment: I tried to use the sub path, but it is not error reason

Comment: Off course I tried both AddJsonBody and AddStringBody

Comment: Ok, I guess I know why it is not working. As you need to reassign back to `request`. Do check my latest answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I reassign back to request:  request = request.AddJsonBody(jsonString, forceSerialize: true);
But not work

Comment: Double serialization. Don't use `forceSerialize: true`. `AddJsonBody` when given a json string will add it as-is. Using that switch, you force it to serialize the json string again. That results in garbage, of course.

Comment: Btw: you should have included that detail in your posted code. @MrMustafa022

Comment: I removed  - forceSerialize: true -  but not work also

Comment: Maybe edit your question with the new error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I detected the problem
I was use these request parameters and when I removed it, it worked successfully

```
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddParameter("user-agent", "swap-erp");
request.AddParameter("accept", "*/*");
request.AddParameter("connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddParameter("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
```

I do not know which one exactly casue the problem but I removed them all

Thank you guys

Answer (score -1):

loop through the object and add the properties as parameters in the request.

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    request.AddParameter(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null).ToString(), false);
}

RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Not working also the same error

Answer (score -1):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://customdomain/registrants");
var request = new RestRequest("https://customdomain/registrants", Method.Post); 

request.AddHeader("authorization", @"Bearer " + token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

object obj = new
{
  first_name = "qqq",
  last_name = "yyy",
  email = "qqq@gmail.com"
};
request.AddBody(obj);
RestResponse result = client.ExecutePost(request);
//or RestResponse result = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Not working also the same error